How to insert k into a loop in IDEA python encryption
my teacher asked me to make an idea cipher, and in python programming, I have very little experience. I need to make k change to 52 in the crypto function, since I have 52 keys, how do I do this?
import random

def bit_number(bit):
    return hex(random.randint(2 ** (bit - 1), 2 ** bit - 1))[2:].zfill(bit // 4)
def separate(mas):
    return [mas[i:i + 4].zfill(4) for i in range(0, len(mas), 4)]
def hex_mod(val, mod):
    result = hex(val % mod)[2:].zfill(4)
    return result if result != "0000" else hex(65536)[2:]
def shift(num):
    bin_number = bin(int(num, 16))[2:].zfill(128)
    shifted_left_bin = bin_number[25:] + bin_number[:25]
    shifted_left_hex = hex(int(shifted_left_bin, 2))[2:].zfill(32)
    return shifted_left_hex
def key_gen(key):
    keys = []
    key_shift = key
    for i in range(8):
        keys.extend(separate(key_shift))
        key_shift = shift(key_shift)
    return keys[:52]
def crypt(message, keys):
    a = [0] * 14
    xshift = [0] * 4
    for i in range(8):
        a[0] = hex_mod(int(message[0], 16) * int(keys[0], 16), 65537)
        a[1] = hex_mod(int(message[1], 16) + int(keys[1], 16), 65536)
        a[2] = hex_mod(int(message[2], 16) + int(keys[2], 16), 65536)
        a[3] = hex_mod(int(message[3], 16) * int(keys[3], 16), 65537)
        a[4] = hex_mod(int(a[0], 16) ^ int(a[2], 16), 65536)
        a[5] = hex_mod(int(a[1], 16) ^ int(a[3], 16), 65536)
        a[6] = hex_mod(int(a[4], 16) * int(keys[4], 16), 65537)
        a[7] = hex_mod(int(a[5], 16) + int(a[6], 16), 65536)
        a[8] = hex_mod(int(a[7], 16) * int(keys[5], 16), 65537)
        a[9] = hex_mod(int(a[6], 16) + int(a[8], 16), 65536)
        xshift[0] = a[10] = hex_mod(int(a[0], 16) ^ int(a[8], 16), 65536)
        xshift[1] = a[11] = hex_mod(int(a[2], 16) ^ int(a[8], 16), 65536)
        xshift[2] = a[12] = hex_mod(int(a[1], 16) ^ int(a[9], 16), 65536)
        xshift[3] = a[13] = hex_mod(int(a[3], 16) ^ int(a[9], 16), 65536)
        for i in range(len(a)):
             if a[i] == "10000":
                 a[i] = "0000"
        message=xshift
    return xshift
x = bit_number(64)
z = bit_number(128)
keys = key_gen(z)
print(z)
message = separate(x)
xshift = crypt(message, keys)
print(xshift)

I tweaked the function, but it didn't give any results

Your code will give results albeit that they may not be what you wanted. For someone with "very little experience" this is some fairly advanced code. Have you perhaps copied it from somewhere and you need to (somehow) modify it? What output do you get and how does it differ from what you want?

No, I did it myself, I have experience in pascal programming, but a little experience in python. I have the idea cipher code. I generate a 128-bit key, then splits it into 8 16-bit parts and cycles the key by 25 bits to the left and so on 7 times, but 52 keys are output. This part is when it works 100% right. But I have a problem in the crypt function where the message is encrypted. I can't make the key be in a loop and change from 1 to 52. And also, on the 7th round of encryption, the cipher text begins to be encrypted incorrectly and gives out the wrong values that it should

although the previous 6 rounds work correctly
